# How to check a site after redirection? DomCrawler. Functional Testing

Tags: symfony, phpunit, domcrawler

How to properly make assertion after redirection?

```
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
$client->followRedirect();
//$response = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("foo")')->count() > 0);
```

Debugger show that `$response` have content that I expect, with a `foo` word, but assertion failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the redirect to the crawler.
Try with this code:

```
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect(),'Submit ok');
    // Assign the redirect to the crawler 
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Correct redirect to page ok");

    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("foo")')->count() > 0);
```

Hope this help